# Is there any way to print Java runtime memory infomation by adding JVM args

Tags: memory, jvm, arguments, profiling

I want to get the heap size **committed** by JVM and the **actual usage** (peak value). The application is short-time.
Is there any way to get the memory information:

1. Not using `jmap`, `jcmd`, ... (which requires pid)
2. Not modifying source code (eg. insert: Runtime.getRuntime() ...)
3. Just by passing arguments to JVM `java -X:someargs ...`

It seems that before jdk1.8 `java -agentlib:hprof=heap` could help, but hprof is removed.

Comment: You can configure a JVM to print out GC statistics when the GC runs, but AFAIK that is all you can do without 1. or 2.

Comment: By the way ... what is the difficulty with getting the pid of a JVM?  The `ps` or `jps` command will tell you what it is.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for the advice~ For those short-time programs (very quick-finish), I guess it is not easy to perform this 'fetch pid & dump heap'.

Answer (score 1):

**JDK 8**

`-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

The heap layout and usage will be printed at VM exit:

```
 PSYoungGen      total 443904K, used 283177K [0x00000000dcc00000, 0x00000000f7f00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 442368K, 63% used [0x00000000dcc00000,0x00000000ee07a6f8,0x00000000f7c00000)
  from space 1536K, 4% used [0x00000000f7d80000,0x00000000f7d90000,0x00000000f7f00000)
  to   space 1536K, 0% used [0x00000000f7c00000,0x00000000f7c00000,0x00000000f7d80000)
 ParOldGen       total 72704K, used 980K [0x0000000096400000, 0x000000009ab00000, 0x00000000dcc00000)
  object space 72704K, 1% used [0x0000000096400000,0x00000000964f5060,0x000000009ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 4568K, capacity 4718K, committed 4992K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 472K, capacity 532K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
```

**JDK 9+**

`-Xlog:gc+heap+exit`

```
[9.405s][info][gc,heap,exit]  garbage-first heap   total 276480K, used 149668K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000800000000)
[9.405s][info][gc,heap,exit]   region size 1024K, 147 young (150528K), 1 survivors (1024K)
[9.405s][info][gc,heap,exit]  Metaspace       used 6335K, capacity 6395K, committed 6784K, reserved 1056768K
[9.405s][info][gc,heap,exit]   class space    used 511K, capacity 530K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
```

`total` is the committed memory; the range `[0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000800000000)` is the reserved space.

If you want to print heap at every GC rather than at VM exit, use
`-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC` in JDK 8, or `-Xlog:gc+heap=debug` in JDK 9+.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I will try it! Does the log summarize the overall heap memory information of the whole program, (I mean the peak value) or just the state at the moment it exits?

Comment: @Miao At exit, not the peak value